# Plotting date of image to the animation map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I used following code to calculate LST and created time-series chart and animation maps.
I now want to add date to each map in the animation. How to fix this?

```
 var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('users/shape');

Map.centerObject(geometry);

//cloud mask
function maskL8sr(col) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = col.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return col.updateMask(mask);
}

//vis params
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B5', 'B6', 'B4'],
  min: 642,
  max: 3307,
  gamma: [1, 0.9, 1.1]
};

var vizParams2 = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

//load the collection:
var col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .map(maskL8sr)
    .filterDate('2020-05-01','2020-08-1')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)});

print('coleccion', col);

//imagen reduction

var image = col.median();
//print('image', image);

Map.addLayer(image, vizParams2);

//median
var ndvi1 = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

//print('ndvi1', ndvi1);

//individual LST images

var col_list = col.toList(col.size());

var LST_col = col_list.map(function (ele) {
  
  var date = ee.Image(ele).get('system:time_start');

  var ndvi = ee.Image(ele).normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  
  // find the min and max of NDVI
  var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0));
  
  var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0));
  
  var fv = (ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV');
  
  var a= ee.Number(0.004);
  var b= ee.Number(0.986);
  
  var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');

  var image = ee.Image(ele);

  var LST = image.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
      'Tb': image.select('B10').multiply(0.1),
      'Ep': fv.multiply(a).add(b)
  });

  return LST.set('system:time_start', date).float().rename('LST');
  
});

LST_col = ee.ImageCollection(LST_col);

print("LST_col", LST_col);

/////////////////

Map.addLayer(ndvi1, ndviParams, 'ndvi');

//select thermal band 10(with brightness tempereature), no calculation 
var thermal= image.select('B10').multiply(0.1);

var b10Params = {min: 306.4, max: 322.8, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

Map.addLayer(thermal, b10Params, 'thermal');

// find the min and max of NDVI
var min = ee.Number(ndvi1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));

//print('min', min );

var max = ee.Number(ndvi1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));

//print('max', max);

//fractional vegetation
var fv = (ndvi1.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV'); 

//print('fv', fv);

//Map.addLayer(fv);

//Emissivity
var a= ee.Number(0.004);
var b= ee.Number(0.986);
var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');

var imageVisParam3 = {min: 0.9865619146722164, max:0.989699971371314};

//Map.addLayer(EM, imageVisParam3,'EMM');

//LST in Celsius Degree bring -273.15
//NB: In Kelvin don't bring -273.15
var LST = col.map(function (image){

  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  
  var LST = image.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
    'Tb': thermal.select('B10'),
    'Ep':EM.select('EMM')
  }).float().rename('LST');
  
  return LST.set('system:time_start', date);
  
});

print(LST);

Map.addLayer(LST, {min: 25, max: 45, palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
]},'LST');

print(
      ui.Chart.image.series({
        imageCollection: LST_col, 
        region: geometry, 
        scale: 30, // nominal scale Landsat imagery 
        xProperty: 'system:time_start' // default
      }));

// Visualize LST

// Define GIF visualization parameters.
var gifParams = {
  'region': geometry.geometry(),
  'dimensions': 900,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 1.5
};

var visParams2 = {
  min: 30,
  max: 40,
  palette: ['blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'
  ],
};


// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = LST_col.select('LST').map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(visParams2);
});


// Print the GIF URL to the console.
//print(rgbVis.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams));

// Render the GIF animation in the console.
print(ui.Thumbnail(rgbVis, gifParams));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that modifying your **rgbVis** function for adapting the code used in my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431584/date-label-on-a-sentinel-2-image-collection-google-earth-engine/431612#431612). Code snippet looks as follows.

```
.
.
.
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text'); // Import gena's package which allows text overlay on image

var annotations = [
  {position: 'left', offset: '1%', margin: '1%', property: 'label', scale: 50} //large scale because image if of the whole world. Use smaller scale otherwise
  ]

// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = LST_col.select('LST').map(function(img) {
  
  var timeStamp = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).format().slice(0,10); // get the time stamp of each frame. This can be any string. Date, Years, Hours, etc.
  timeStamp = ee.String('Date: ').cat(ee.String(timeStamp)); //convert time stamp to string 
  
  var image = img.visualize(visParams2).set({'label': timeStamp})
  
  var annotated = text.annotateImage(image, {}, geometry, annotations); // create a new image with the label overlayed using gena's package

  return annotated;
});
.
.
.
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/552c7f160f57f16a6b6ece2cb51a1e7e) en GEE code editor, I got result of following image by using an arbitrary geometry in USA. Dates for each image were placed in upper left corner; as it can be visualized in image generated for 2020-07-11 date (however, all date images can be visualized).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @xunilk for your help. Code runs well but doesn't produce animation. Have you got any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Does my code work for you?

Comment: Yes yourse worked, but mine didn't.

Comment: Probably you have images with null min/max values. I had to select one area without these values for running the script. So, select only one image in your area (of course with min/max values) for generating the animation. If it works you have to filter your collection for eliminating these images.